# How should I deal with accessibility reports?

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, user-experience

I need to draw up an accessibility report that is imposed by the European Union for some UI/UX projects. The problem is that the guidelines are not exactly clear and I would like to have more explanations regarding the compilation and, as a consequence, the calculation of the resulting score.

In particular I was interested in knowing how to deal with items that can be considered as NA (Not Applicable); for example: let's suppose that the application for which the accessibility declaration is being drawn up does not contain pre-recorded audio or video elements, in in this case the points involved in the report ( [AUDIO & VIDEO STATEMENT W3 CONSORTIUM](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/audio-only-and-video-only-prerecorded) ) are not applicable for evaluation; as such, can they be subtracted and excluded from the total score?

Does anyone have an answer? Understanding how to deal with this point would also allow me to adjust the score, which would also drastically change the compliancy based on the accessibility threshold.

I tried to contact the authorities in charge and they were unable to give me an answer; I have also searched from various sources, but the situation is not very clear.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not really a programming question so your question might get flagged.  Also, can you post a reference to the EU requirement for the type of report you need? Hopefully that reference talks about the "score" that should be computed. It sort of sounds like you need a VPAT ([Voluntary Product Accessibility Template](https://www.itic.org/policy/accessibility/vpat)) or ACR (Accessibility Conformance Report)

Comment: Hi @slugolicious thank you for your reply. I know it's not really a programming question, but i'm desperate since i can't find any resource on how to deal with this problem.

Being Italian, the agency that takes care of providing the specifications for compiling the report is AgID [AgID Accesibility](https://www.agid.gov.it/en/design-servizi/web-accessibility). The guidelines are taken from the Web Accessibility Directive (WU) 2016/2102 issued by the European Union [EU Accessibility](https://digital-strategy.ec.europa.eu/en/policies/web-accessibility)

Comment: I would recommend posting your question to the [WebAIM discussion group](https://webaim.org/discussion/) and to the [accessibility slack channel](https://web-a11y.slack.com/). Let me know if you need an invite to join the slack community.

Comment: Actually, there is no guidelines in the WAD. The guidelines are in [EN 301 549](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EN_301_549), which are based on WCAG 2. To my knowledge, neither mentions a scoring system. The [French RGAA](https://design.numerique.gouv.fr/accessibilite-numerique/rgaa/) work with scoring, and simply exclude the N/A values for the score. Only knowledge of your national laws would allow to determine how to do this according to law.